# lucene index file randomly crash and need to reindex

Tags: java, full-text-search, lucene, search-engine

How you all deal with such issues of occasionally need to reindex? what recommendation do you suggest to minimize this?

Comment: Some background is needed: How large is what you are trying to index? What kind of crashes? (error messages)? In my experience with Lucene, almost all crashes had to do with my programming errors...

Comment: take liferay open source project for example. i want to list down measurements that able to minimize the crash

Comment: If your Lucene instance is embedded in liferay, I guess liferay should provide you with guidelines and logs about the Lucene indexes, as well as ways to configure them. This is very different than using a bare Lucene index in your program. As a very general guideline, I suggest you measure the overall number of documents you have in the index, the number you index per hour and the optimize() interval. I believe a liferay user forum should give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a really large dataset, then i would recommend you to maintain a second server that has a backup of your index, so that you can have **no single point of failure**. You can synchronize this "backup" when ever you finish re-indexing and thus serve as a second search server that shares requests. If one fails, then the other can back-it-up. This is a simple yet robust approach to your problem and recommended for small-to-medium setups.